# Can I enable warning for comparing a enum and a non enum values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I recently debugged an issue which was caused because an enum was being compared with a non-enum value.  Here is a simplified example:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyType) {
    TypeVal1,
};

...

MyType type = TypeVal1;
int randomValue = 0;

BOOL compareTypeAndPrimiative = (randomValue == typeA); // No warning
```

Is it possible to turn on a warning for this?

I could suppress if if needed by explicitly casting:

```
BOOL iKnowWhatImDoing = (randomValue == (int) typeA);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for this kind of warning because C enums are not strongly typed, and I believe the standards require them to be treated as ints (or unsigned ints). Comparing them with regular integers has always been allowed as part of the C standard, and a warning of this type would end up flagging a lot of correct code. I'm sure somebody can link to the appropriate section of the C standards.

Particularly with iOS and Apple APIs, you will find that enum values are often used as bitmasks. In these situations it is common to write code like this:

```
if ((value & flag) == kFlag) { ... }
```

You could argue that using enums for this purpose is a bad idea, but you would probably end up having to disable this warning for all sorts of code.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran through LLVM manual and it seems there is no option for this. Then I tried to turn on all the compiler warnings (`-Weverything`), however there was no warning your `enum` case.

So the answer is no.

The best solution to avoid such bugs is to name the variables/constants appropiately. Make obvious what the variable/constant represent. Then the error in comparison should be obvious, too.